# How to make checkbox true when input is a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with this challenge for a long time. Any help would be appreciated.
I want to do this:
if input has number then checkbox => true
if input has letters then checkbox => true

Comment: Please share some code of what you already have tried.

Comment: Write your component's code in your question.

Comment: and in both cases (input has number, and input has letters) you wrote => true! is it by mistake? how about if input has both numbers and letters!

Comment: So... if the textbox has _anything_ checkbox is true? PS [here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: @Andy yes if input has numbers or letter checkbox is trye

Comment: What if the input value is `;'-3k`? - do you want the checkbox to be checked even though there are special characters? As long as it's got at least one letter/number it should be checked? @MahdiAlavitabar

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a good answer with the information you have provided, however. If you want to check if the content of the input contains letters or numbers the best approach would be to add a [onchange event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to the input, where you pass the content through a regex like so:

```
/^[\da-zA-Z]*$/g.test(input.value)
```

Or, if you also want to check for spaces use this regex:

```
/^[\da-zA-Z\s]*$/g.test(input.value)
```

If that returns true, then just set the checkbox to checked

Answer (score 0):

Use state to maintain the input value, and have the checkbox call a function that [tests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) whether the value contains *only* letters or numbers.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  // When the input changes update the state
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setInput(value);
  }

  // Does the input value contain any
  // letters or numbers?
  function checkInput() {
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(input);
  }

  // `checkInput` returns a boolean that sets
  // the value of the checkbox
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onInput={handleInput} />
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checkInput()} />
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```